# TabBarView with dynamic Container height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So this is my layout structure

This is the main screen

```
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    _buildCarousel(),
    _buildHomeTabBar(),
  ],
)
```

And this is the HomeTabBar screen

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  child:
    DefaultTabController(
      length: myTabs.length,
      initialIndex: 0,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: myTabs,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 600,
              child: 
              TabBarView(
                children: [
                  ChildScreen(),
                  ChildScreen2(),
                  ChildScreen3(),
                ],
              )
          )
        ],
      ))
);
```

I want to get rid off that `Container` height. How do we do this?

The `ChildScreen` is getting the data from REST it is actually a `GridView.Builder` so the height of `Container` should be dynamic.

Sorry I missed layout for `ChildScreen` actually like this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  // shrinkWrap: true,
child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        StreamBuilder(
          stream: categoryBloc.categoryList,
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Category>> snapshot){
              if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot!=null) {
                if(snapshot.data.length > 0){
                  return buildCategoryList(snapshot);
                }
                else if(snapshot.data.length==0){
                    return Text('No Data');
                }
              }
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return ErrorScreen(errMessage: snapshot.error.toString());
              }     
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

          },
        ),       
    ]
  )
);
```

So inside `StreamBuilder` is `GridView.Builder`.
The main thing I want to remove `Container` height. It looks ugly on different devices...

So if I remove the height it will not show on screen and throw error

> I/flutter (  493): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1578:12)
>   I/flutter (  493): #3      RenderSliverList.performLayout.advance (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:200:17)
>   I/flutter (  493): #4      RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:233:19)
>   I/flutter (  493): #5      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
>   I/flutter (  493): #6      RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
>   I/flutter (  493): #7      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
>   I/flutter (  493): #8      RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:405:13)
>   I/flutter (  493): #9      RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1316:12)
>   I/flutter (  493): #10     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1234:20)
>   I/flutter (  493): #11     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
>   I/flutter (  493): #12     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
>   I/flutter (  493): #13     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)

Comment: What error you get - when you remove Container height. - `height: 600,`?

Comment: It will not show up on screen. I will update for the error message.

Comment: is `shrinkWrap: true,` in GridView.Builder ?

Comment: @anmol.majhail yes `shrinkWrap: true` on GridView.Builder

Comment: This is how I Solved a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/66540036/4150479

Comment: i think this answer can fix this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57871235/5319007

Comment: Use this package which I created for the same.
https://pub.dev/packages/autoscale_tabbarview

Answer (score 101):

I had similar task at my project. The root of the problem is that you are trying to put `TabBarView` (scrollable widget that trying to be as big as possible), in a column widget, that have no height.

One of solutions is get rid of scrollable widgets that wraps your `TabBarView` in this example `ListView` + `Column`. And use `NestedScrollView` instead of them. You need to put `_buildCarousel()` and `TabBar` in the `headerSliverBuilder` part, and `TabBarView` inside the body of `NestedScrollView`.

I don't know how is your design looks, but `NestedScrollView` by default opens up to 100% height of screen view.  So if you want to make an effect that everything is on one screen, it easer to just block scrolling, by change `ScrollController` behavior when it’s needed.

In this example I’m blocking scrolling on third tab, but you can check visibility of the last item of the grid view. Just add the key to the last item, and check its position on the screen.

Hope it’s help.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final bodyGlobalKey = GlobalKey();
  final List<Widget> myTabs = [
    Tab(text: 'auto short'),
    Tab(text: 'auto long'),
    Tab(text: 'fixed'),
  ];
  TabController _tabController;
  ScrollController _scrollController;
  bool fixedScroll;

  Widget _buildCarousel() {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 100),
        Positioned.fill(child: Align(alignment: Alignment.center, child: Text('Slider'))),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(_smoothScrollToTop);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _scrollListener() {
    if (fixedScroll) {
      _scrollController.jumpTo(0);
    }
  }

  _smoothScrollToTop() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(
      0,
      duration: Duration(microseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.ease,
    );

    setState(() {
      fixedScroll = _tabController.index == 2;
    });
  }

  _buildTabContext(int lineCount) => Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: lineCount,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Text('some content');
          },
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
          return [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(child: _buildCarousel()),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                labelColor: Colors.redAccent,
                isScrollable: true,
                tabs: myTabs,
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: [_buildTabContext(2), _buildTabContext(200), _buildTabContext(2)],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
.

Another way to get what you want could be creating custom `TabView` widget.

Comment: Not OP, but can you show an example code? I'm still stuck here.

Comment: @Kherel Ketchil how can we keep tabbars on top of screen during scrolling list to top?

Comment: sure we just need to move TabBar from headerSliverBuilder part of the NestedScrollView to body part

Comment: Wasted about an hour with singlechildscrollview ... So grateful

Comment: After 6 days of thinking and trying different methods. this solved my problem. Thank you

Comment: if i have to sticky tabbar on header with this?

Comment: @ParthGodhani you try to use SliverPersistentHeader with pinned: true parameter

Comment: Been looking for a solution for this the whole night. Thank you!

Comment: How do we keep the tabs on scrolling up not to be hidden past the safe area, when hidden, scrolling downwards is not possible. Have tried for two days in vain. Help.

Comment: So great solution. Thanks for sharing that saved my time

Comment: After 2 days of googling now i have an answer

Comment: the red area is the container height. For me it takes full height: https://i.ibb.co/YXwMVPy/Screenshot-2021-05-31-at-17-35-57.png

Comment: How to disable the scroll if the content is less?

Comment: this solution worked for me til I had to user a StreamBuilder. Having the controller the tab content doesn't change

Comment: I implemented this in my project but I received this error ```Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.```

Answer (score 34):

If you are getting error with Expanded also, then don't use TabBarView create custom TabBarView

1. Get index from onTap, is property of TabBar.
2. Then use if else in onTap function which index to be selected and initialize global varibale with index.
3. Then use Builder Widgets for building your TabBarView. Again In Builder you are going to use if else to get which index selected. Then return your widget in if else.

In this case you can get maximum or minimum height of your widget. You don't need to specify container height.

> _selectedTabBar is a global variable

```
 Column(children: [
               TabBar(
                       onTap: (index) {
                          print(index);                                  
                          setState(() {
                                _selectedTabbar = index;
                          });
                        },
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Tab1',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Tab2',
                          ),
                          Tab(
                            text: 'Tab3',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    
                      Builder(builder: (_) {
                        if (_selectedTabbar == 0) {
                          return Container();//1st custom tabBarView
                        } else if (_selectedTabbar == 1) {
                          return Container();//2nd tabView
                        } else {
                          return Container(); //3rd tabView
                        }
                      }),
]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did this but with an AnimatedSwitcher and it all works great now!

Comment: @tapizquent I'm trying to do the same thing with an AnimatedSwitcher to get the sliding effect between the tabs content, do you mind showing the code for how you solved it with the AnimatedSwitcher?

Comment: It is better to use IndexedStack as it provides the index property instead of ifs in the builder

Comment: This doesn't work inside a Dialog. :-(
Any solution ?

Answer (score 8):

Working Solution:
you need to have expanded in two place

1. Above DefaultTabController.
2. Container of Containers.

```dart
Expanded(
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.grey, width: 0.5))),
        child: TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
              Container(),
              Container(),
              Container(),
        ])),),
```

One is not enough.

Answer (score 5):

The default TabBarView does not allows to have children with dynamic height. This package tried to solve that by extending default TabBarView and make required changes. AutoScaleTabbarView allows to have children with dynamic height.
You can use this [autoscale_tabbarview](https://pub.dev/packages/autoscale_tabbarview/install) library to solve your case.

first, run this command in your terminal

```
flutter pub add autoscale_tabbarview
```

then, Import it to your dart file

```
import 'package:autoscale_tabbarview/autoscale_tabbarview.dart';
```

finally, replace `TabBarView` with `AutoScaleTabbarView` and remove height from your container

Answer (score 3):

1- You need to add your content into a list

2- Then put your tabBarView into a container

3- Assuming your items have a fixed height, define height of the container as height of your widget and just multiply by your current index content or list length

Ex: `height: 90*_items.length.toDouble(),`

Answer (score 2):

I use this package: https://pub.dev/packages/autoscale_tabbarview
by use this it can use TabBarView inside SingleChildScrollView

```
import 'package:autoscale_tabbarview/autoscale_tabbarview.dart';

AutoScaleTabBarView( // replace TabBarView with AutoScaleTabBarView
    children: myTabs.map((Tab tab) {
      final String label = tab.text!.toLowerCase();
      return Center(
        child: Text(
          'This is the $label tab',
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 36),
        ),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
```

Comment: Bless you God! I spend 4 hours trying to resolve this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your listview with an [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget:

Using an `Expanded` widget makes a child of a `Row`, `Column`, or `Flex` expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a Row or vertically for a Column). If multiple children are expanded, the available space is divided among them according to the flex factor.

```
Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 120,
  itemExtent: 32,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
        Text(' Entry $index'),
      ],
    );
  },
))
```

Comment: Not working. Sorry I missed the layout for ChildScreen I will update...

Comment: This doesn't work since `Expanded` (alike `TabBarView`) will try to be a long as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had same requirement but need to show tab bar with dynamic height in bottom sheet, so I tried below code and it worked perfectly fine with me

```
class BottomSheetScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomSheetScreenState createState() => _BottomSheetScreenState();
}

class _BottomSheetScreenState extends State<BottomSheetScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late TabController _tabController;
  int _selectedTabbar = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
        onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return StatefulBuilder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
                return Wrap(
                  children: [
                    Column(children: [
                      TabBar(
                        controller: _tabController,
                        onTap: (index) {
                          print(index);
                          setState(() {
                            _selectedTabbar = index;
                          });
                        },
                        tabs: [
                          Tab(text: 'Tab1'),
                          Tab(text: 'Tab2'),
                          Tab(text: 'Tab3'),
                        ],
                      ),
                      IntrinsicHeight(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            _selectedTabbar == 0 ? Text("Tab1 content") : _selectedTabbar == 1 ? Text("Tab2 content") : Text("Tab3 content"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text("bottom content"),
                    ]),
                  ],
                );
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code sample doesn't seem to use `TabBarView`, which the OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap tabbarview with expanded widget to avoid fixed height of Container