# Flutter: TabBarView inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll, widget

My problem is that I want a TabBarView inside a SingleChildScrollView but it gives me this error:
`RenderFlex` children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

If I remove the `SingleChildScrollView` it works but I need the widget because then I want to push a ListView that it scrolls with the `TabBar`, like Instagram.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.photo_library,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.perm_media,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            indicatorColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: [
              Expanded(child: Container()),
              Expanded(child: Container())
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )));
  }
}
```

Changes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.photo_library,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.perm_media,
                  size: 30,
                ),
              ),
            ],
            labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
            indicatorColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(child:TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: [
              Container(),
              Container()
            ]),
          ),)
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: were u able to solve this issue?

Comment: how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 20):

You can use `NestedScrollView` to fix this issue.

The below code helped me to solve:

```
NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, value) {
        return [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Header()
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: TabBar(
              controller: _controller,
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.x)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.y)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.z)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
    body: Container(
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          page1(),
          page2(),
          page3(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

For further explanation, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57383014/6747251)

Comment: this woooooorrrrkkkssssss....  finally. THANKS REVERIE!

Answer (score 1):

The TabBarView requires a finite height which the SingleChildScrollView cant offer. The Problem is you are using expanded in a column that is inside a SingleChildScrollView.

---

This answer from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56326005/how-to-use-expanded-in-singlechildscrollview) might help you

The answer is in the error itself. When the column is inside a view that is scrollable, the column is trying to shrink-wrap its content but since you used Expanded as a child of the column it is working opposite to the column trying to shrink-wrap its children. Both are trying to achieve an exactly opposite task. Og

This is causing this error because these two directives are completely opposite to each other.
As mentioned in the error logs try the following:
Consider setting `mainAxisSize` to `MainAxisSize.min` (for column) and using `FlexFit.loose` fits for the flexible (use Flexible rather than Expanded).

Comment: I try it and the same error. I push the new code in the post. How I do it?

Comment: For once give the TabBarView some height using container

Comment: Of course it works nice with height, but i want an expanded `TabBarView`

Comment: Do one thing remove singlechildscrollview from the top of the scaffold and Replace the Flexible with Expanded. Inside the Expanded keep the singlechildscrollview and then the TabBarView

Comment: It doesn't work and i want the `TabBar` inside too. I added the change to the post

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. My Solution was to Use a Container instead of a TabBarView to show the children(tabs).

You can switch the content of this container based on the index selected By TabBar.

Of course if you need swipe gesture to move between tabs you need to add that as well for me it was not needed. Code looks Something like this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Screen({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _builderPageController;
  List<Widget> _tabs;
  List<Tab> _tabItems;
  int selectedtabIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initTabController();
    _setUpTabComponents();
    _preprareTabItems();
  }

  Column _showWidgets() {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          // your non tab widgets goes here
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Material(
          elevation: 3,
          child: TabBar(
            tabs: _tabItems,
            controller: _builderPageController,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
            labelColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
              fontSize: 12.0,
            ),
            unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, fontSize: 12.0),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return _tabs[selectedtabIndex];
              },
            ))
      ],
    );
  }

  void _initTabController() {
    // inits Tabcontroller for Tabview
    _builderPageController = TabController(
      length: 3,
      vsync: this,
      initialIndex: selectedtabIndex,
    );
    _builderPageController.addListener(() {
      // updated index and calls the set state
      // to switch the content of the tab based on the index clicked
      selectedtabIndex = _builderPageController.index;
      setState(() {
        _builderPageController.index;
      });
    });
  }

  void _setUpTabComponents() {
    // sets up Tab headers
    _tabItems = [
      Tab(child: Text('Tab1')),
      Tab(child: Text('Tab2')),
      Tab(child: Text('Tab3')),
    ];
  }

  List<Widget> _preprareTabItems() {
    // views to show on each tab
    // remove height once you add your contents
    return _tabs = <Widget>[
      Container(
        // first tab content
        height: 400,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
        // second tab content
        height: 600,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      Container(
        // third  tab content
        height: 900,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(child: _showWidgets());
  }
}
```