# How to fix unbounded height issue?

Tags: flutter

I need a component to be inserted in a SingleChildScrollView children's list that has one or two tabs.

Here's my `build()`method:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// TODO: Make firmware update support for iOS asap
    final isBleFirmwareUpdateSupported = Platform.isAndroid;

    return DefaultTabController(
        length: isBleFirmwareUpdateSupported ? 2 : 1,
        child: Column(children: [
          // === "Firmware BLE update"
          Text(i18n_Firmware_update.i18n,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),

          spacer,
          // == Pick Wifi or BLE
          TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.wifi)),
              if (isBleFirmwareUpdateSupported)
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.bluetooth)),
            ],
          ),

          Center(
              child: TabBarView(children: [
            Center(child: Text("WiFi")),
            Center(child: Text("BLE"))
      ]))
        ]));
  }
}
```

But I get the error

> FlutterError (Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height.
> Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.)

Of course, if I do:

```
          Container(
              height: 600,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: TabBarView(children: [
```

The error disappears.

So my question is how to transform the code so that the container compute an engloging children box by itself?

Comment: Where is the `SingleChildScrollView`? What is and where is the `spacer` declaration? What've you tried? Try to provide a minimal reproducible exemple of this exception in your context.

Comment: Maybe this post helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62484998/flutter-tabbarview-inside-singlechildscrollview

Comment: Wrap every child of the column with Expanded widget and if spacer is a Spacer() Widget, then remove it

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the widget with `Expanded` or you can wrap using `SizedBox`:

```
SizedBox.expand(
    child: TabBarView(),
  )
```

Another way:

```
SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height 
    child: TabBarView(),
  )
```