Listview inside TabBarView inside Column inside SingleChildScrollView
Currently, I have set a fixed height for the TabBarView using a SizedBox, but I want to remove this fixed height and make it dynamic. However, without the SizedBox, TabBarView collapses. How can I achieve a dynamic height for TabBarView that adjusts based on the content of its child ListView.builder widgets?
I have tried using shrinkWrap: true for the ListView.builder widgets, but it does not seem to affect the height of TabBarView. Any suggestions or alternative approaches are appreciated. Thank you!
I need to remove this SizedBox and make the height of the TabBarViews dynamic in nature.
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 1000,
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: tabController,
                      // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          // controller: scrollController,
                          itemCount: 6,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return CoursesTab(
                              index: index,
                            );
                          },
                        ),

Whole Code Below
import ~~~
import 'package:provider/provider.dart' as p;
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class InstituteInfoScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final String? id;
  final String? source;

  const InstituteInfoScreen({super.key, this.id, this.source});

  @override
  ConsumerState<InstituteInfoScreen> createState() => _InstituteInfoScreenState();
}

class _InstituteInfoScreenState extends ConsumerState<InstituteInfoScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;
  final ScrollController _scrollController1 = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 5,
      vsync: this,
      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    );
    // TODO: implement initState
    // var pixels = _scrollController1.position.pixels;
    // _bool = pixels > 373;
    _scrollController1.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController1.position.pixels > 415 &&
          !(ref.watch(InstituteInfoRiverpodProviders.toggleScrollUi))) {
        ref.read(InstituteInfoRiverpodProviders.toggleScrollUi.notifier).update((state) => true);
      }
      if (_scrollController1.position.pixels < 415 &&
          ref.watch(InstituteInfoRiverpodProviders.toggleScrollUi)) {
        ref.read(InstituteInfoRiverpodProviders.toggleScrollUi.notifier).update((state) => false);
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final StudentProvider student = p.Provider.of<StudentProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return SafeArea(
      child: ref
          .watch(
            InstituteInfoRepo.getInstituteByIdFutureProvider(
              GetInstituteParams(
                instituteId: widget.id!,
                latitude: student.latitude!,
                longitude: student.longitude!,
              ),
            ),
          )
          .when(
            data: (institute) {
              return Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  elevation: 0,
                  backgroundColor: const Color(0xfffff6ff),
                  foregroundColor: const Color(0xfffff6ff),
                  primary: false,
                  surfaceTintColor: const Color(0xfffff6ff),
                  // shadowColor: const Color(0xfffff6ff),
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(24),
                    ),
                  ),
                  leading: IconButton(
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/new-ui/icons/back_button.svg',
                      color: const Color(0xFF201926),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/images/new-ui/icons/call.svg',
                        // color: Color(0xFF201926),
                      ),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/images/new-ui/icons/message_circle.svg',
                        // color: Color(0xFF201926),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  bottom: ref.watch(InstituteInfoRiverpodProviders.toggleScrollUi)
                      ? PreferredSize(
                          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(130), // Adjust the height as needed
                          child: Container(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 24.0,
                              right: 24.0,
                              top: 16.0,
                            ),
                            child: CustomBottomWidget(
                              tabController: tabController,
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : null,
                ),
                body: SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _scrollController1,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      /// Other Widgets
                     
                      const SizedBox(height: 24),
                      ref.watch(InstituteInfoRiverpodProviders.toggleScrollUi)
                          ? Container()
                          : Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
                            child: CustomBottomWidget(
                                tabController: tabController,
                              ),
                          ),

/// I need to remove this SizedBox* and make the height of the TabBarViews dynamic in nature.
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 1000,
                        child: TabBarView(
                          controller: tabController,
                          // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          children: [
                            ListView.builder(
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              // controller: scrollController,
                              itemCount: 6,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return CoursesTab(
                                  index: index,
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: AmenitiesTab(
                                amenities: [
                                  Amenity(
                                    name: 'Wi-Fi',
                                    icon: 'wifi',
                                  ),
                                  Amenity(
                                    name: 'Parking',
                                    icon: 'parking',
                                  ),
                                  Amenity(
                                    name: 'Swimming Pool',
                                    icon: 'pool',
                                  ),
                                  Amenity(
                                    name: 'Gym',
                                    icon: 'gym',
                                  ),
                                  Amenity(
                                    name: 'Spa',
                                    icon: 'spa',
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            const AboutInstituteTab(),
                            ReviewsTab(
                              reviews: [
                                Review(
                                  name: 'John Doe',
                                  review:
                                      'The course felt so personalized that I could follow it all along. The instructor knew exactly what he was doing and it was easy for me to grasp the basic concepts as well. Highly recommended!',
                                ),
                                Review(
                                  name: 'Jane Doe',
                                  review:
                                      'The course felt so personalized that I could follow it all along. The instructor knew exactly what he was doing and it was easy for me to grasp the basic concepts as well. Highly recommended!',
                                ),
                                Review(
                                  name: 'Alice Doe',
                                  review:
                                      'The course felt so personalized that I could follow it all along. The instructor knew exactly what he was doing and it was easy for me to grasp the basic concepts as well. Highly recommended!',
                                ),
                                Review(
                                  name: 'Alice Doe',
                                  review:
                                      'The course felt so personalized that I could follow it all along. The instructor knew exactly what he was doing and it was easy for me to grasp the basic concepts as well. Highly recommended!',
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            const GalleryTab(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            error: (error, stackTrace) {
              return Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    error.toString(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            loading: () => Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: GifView.asset(
                  "assets/gif/loading.gif",
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomBottomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final TabController tabController;

  const CustomBottomWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.tabController,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 50,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 8.0,
            bottom: 8.0,
            left: 13.55,
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
            border: Border.all(
              color: const Color(0xff9F88B1),
              width: 1.5,
            ),
            color: const Color(0xffffffff),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Text('Search...'),
              Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/new-ui/icons/search.svg',
                      color: const Color(0xff201926),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  ),
                  SvgPicture.asset(
                    'assets/images/new-ui/icons/divider.svg',
                    color: const Color(0xff9F88B1),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/images/new-ui/icons/voice.svg',
                      color: const Color(0xff7D23E0),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ), // Search Widget
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        TabBar(
          tabs: const [
            Tab(
              text: 'Courses',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Amenities',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'About Institute',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Reviews',
            ),
            Tab(
              text: 'Gallery',
            ),
          ],
          // indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
          tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
          labelColor: const Color(0xff7D23E0),
          unselectedLabelColor: const Color(0xff4C4452),
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          isScrollable: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
          // labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 0),
          physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            height: 1.5,
          ),
          labelStyle: const TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Avenir',
            fontSize: 16,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            height: 1.5,
            letterSpacing: 0.16,
          ),
          controller: tabController,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}




Wrap your TabBarView with Expanded instead of SizedBox

@RavindraS.Patil I've tried wrapping it with Expanded but it still gives me RenderFlex error caught: RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Refer my below simple example hope its help to you.

I simply added this package AutoScaleTabbarView, replaced the TabBarView widget with this & it solved my problem.

Refer below code I have try simple example hope its help to you. Read more about TabBar
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const TabBarApp());

class TabBarApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      home: const TabBarExample(),
    );
  }
}

class TabBarExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabBarExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<TabBarExample> createState() => _TabBarExampleState();
}

class _TabBarExampleState extends State<TabBarExample>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('TabBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 30,
            child: TabBar(
              dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                ListView.builder(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  // controller: scrollController,
                  itemCount: 6,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text("It's List here");
                  },
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("It's rainy here"),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text("It's sunny here"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Sorry for the confusion. In my provided code snippet, I wrapped the Column inside a SingleChildScrollView because there are additional children within the Column. Following those children, I included the TabBarView widget.
Additionally, I'm implementing scrolling through the screen using scrollController1 because I need to modify certain components of the screen when a particular amount of scrolling is reached.
Unfortunately, the solution provided isn't helping me address the specific issue.

your code is like - SingleChildScrollView->'Column'->[TabBar->TabBarView, Other Widgtes]?

TabBarView isn't inside TabBar, its a seperate widget, but the tabBarController is attached so it changes accordingly. It is like - SingleChildScrollView -> Column -> [Other Widget (including TabBar), SizedBox(child: TabBarView(children: [ListView.builder(), Other Widgets],),),]

Cant understand your problem

Read the code I've provided above, you'll understand what I am talking about. I need to remove the SizedBox.

Kinda similar to this problem right here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54642710/tabbarview-with-dynamic-container-height
